# String parsing using Python?

Tags: python, string-matching

Given a string such as 'helloyellowellow', parse all the valid strings from the given string. (Eg: [[hell,hello,yellow],[low, low]........]

I am looking for the most optimized way to write the code. Here is mine but I am not sure if this is the best way.

Full disclosure - This was an interview question

```
master = []

#   Dictionary for us to look up words   
def is_word(inputstr):
    #returns True/False


def processstring(fstr,secstr,li):
    if is_word(fstr): 
        li.append(fstr)
    if len(secstr) == 0:
        if len(li) != 0:
            master.append(li)
        return
    processstring(fstr+secstr[0], secstr[1:len(secstr)],li)



def wrapperprocess(inpstr):
    li = []
    if len(inpstr) == 0:
        return
    processstring('',inpstr,li)
    wrapperprocess(inpstr[1:len(inpstr)])


wrapperprocess('helloyellowellow')
print master
```

Comment: In your solution, looks like you forgot to `return li`. A better approach is to `yield` the matched words, instead of maintaining a list, appending to it, and returning it.

Answer (score 3):

Since you mentioned you're looking for an efficient algorithm, and assuming you get the dictionary in advance (and not just as a callable predicate), you can use the [Aho–Corasick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) algorithm.

Of course, if the input text is short, a more naive algorithm will be faster, for avoiding the "expensive" pre-processing of the dictionary.

Plus, an alternative python-answer: here's a simple way to simply check each substring:

```
def gen_words(txt):
    n = len(txt)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i+1, n+1):
            subtxt = txt[i:j]
            if is_word(subtxt):
                yield subtxt
```

For uniqueness, do:

```
all_words = set(gen_words(txt))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
tgt='helloyellowellow'

with open('/usr/share/dict/words') as f:
    for word in f:
        word=word.strip()
        if word in tgt and len(word)>1:
            print word
```

Prints:

```
el
ell
he
hell
hello
lo
low
loy
ow
owe
we
well
ye
yell
yellow
```

If you are just looking for the function `is_word` that you have undefined, you can play with something like this:

```
def is_word(word, dic='/usr/share/dict/words'):
    if not hasattr(is_word, 'words'):
        with open(dic) as f:
            is_word.words={word.strip() for word in f}

    return word in is_word.words and len(word)>1
```

As a default data structure, Python sets have an average [look-up time of O(1)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity). You are very unlikely to write something on your own that is faster.

Comment: Thanks for the code. But, how is it efficient if you are looking up every single word from the dictionary to match with your string? Won't you be doing millions of matches when only a small subset of them match?

Comment: What is 'efficient' in this case? On my (old, slow) computer, this executes in 88 ms. Just printing 'hello' in Python takes 22 ms, so at 60ms more it is pretty fast. Only one word at a time is in memory, so it is pretty memory efficient. Since it took me about 30 seconds to write, it is pretty programmer efficient. In what way do you wish to be more efficient? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It's good problem to solve with,

Use `Wordnet` package,

While parsing your given string start with some index and keep tormenting your index value
for every incremental on the index, check the existence of the same word using wordnet, it will tell you weather the particular sub-string is a meaningful or not !

To install `wordnet`:

```
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Wordnet-bn/1.0
```